# How to show a property of type Object in a list

Tags: c#, object, xamarin, xamarin.forms, model-binding

I want to show a list of Chemical Substances in the following way

[image: screenshoot]

the problem is that in my view, I'm not showing anything!

When I open my ResultadosHDSViewModel I have the following method in the constructor

```
  ObservableCollection<Sqs> sqss;   

  public ObservableCollection<Sqs> Sqss
  {
      get
   {
       return sqss;
   }
      set
      {
         if (sqss != value)
      {
          sqss = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                     this,
                     new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Sqss)));
       }
}
                }

         public ResultadosHDSViewModel()
         {           
                LoadSustancias();
         }

    public async void LoadSustancias()
    {                     

       var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();           

       var sustancias = mainViewModel.FabricanteForm.Results.Sqs.Select(c => c.Where(v => v.Column == 2)
                             .Select(u => u).ToList().FirstOrDefault());    

           foreach (var item in sustancias)
           {
                Sqss.Add(item); 
           }
    }
```

The result of my LINQ query "sustancias" is:

[image: debug]

the problem is that by going through this INumerable with a foreach to fill my ObservableCollection Sqss my application falls and bursts!

I attach my view to which I want to store the data (Value)
ResultadosHDSView.XAML:

```
<StackLayout 
        BindingContext="{Binding ResultadosHDS}"
        Padding="5"> 

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sqss}"
                  SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                         Padding="16,0,0,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                          
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <Button 
                                    Text="VER"  
                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"                                   
                                    HeightRequest="35" 
                                    WidthRequest="55"
                                    Command="{Binding VerCommand}"/>
                            <Button 
                                    Text="HDS"   
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"                                        
                                    HeightRequest="35"
                                    WidthRequest="55"
                                    Command="{Binding HDSCommand}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
```

I also attach the definition of my classes involved

```
 public class FabricanteFormResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userMessage")]
        public string UserMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "results")]
        public FabricanteForm Results { get; set; }
    }

public class FabricanteForm
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "columns")]
        public List<int> Columns { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sqs")]
        public List<List<Sqs>> Sqs { get; set; }
    }

 public class Sqs
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "field")]
        public string Field { get; set;}

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
        public int Column { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
        public Object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, my Object "Value" property is of type Object, it is just the one I want to show in the Binding of my view!

What am I doing wrong? the Linq type query? Should I cast my item before I bin it? how can I do it? any help for me?

Comment: you need to initialize sqss first.  "sqss = new ObservableCollection<Sqs>()";

Comment: In the constructor?¿ in the method? where? @Jason

Comment: anywhere, but before you try to use it.  The constructor would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling the method from constructor I would replace the foreach loop with this:

```
Sqss = new ObservableCollection<Sqs>(sustancias);
```

Your LINQ could also be improved a little:

```
var sustancias = fabricanteForm.Sqs.Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Column == 2));
```

Since you are using FirstOrDefault this leads me to believe there could be items with no Column 2 so if you only want the ones that are not null:

```
Sqss = new ObservableCollection<Sqs>(sustancias.Where(s => s != null));
```

Maybe also change the method signature as well. Private unless you plan to call it outside of the constructor. Since there are no async methods called it shouldn't be async either.

```
    private void LoadSustancias()
    {
```

Comment: Its implementation falls and bursts in the following line Sqss = new ObservableCollection <Sqs> (substances); , thanks for your help, but I'm not managing to save the data to my Sqss list @Skall

Comment: "falls and bursts" is not helpful information.  If it's crashing, what is the specific exception that is causing the crash?  Also, you should probably be initializing "sqss" the private variable, not "Sqss" the public property.

Comment: @Jason, true you could call the private field. I used the public property since it sends a property changed notification but since this is used from the constructor it wouldn't matter.